# XQuery - Remove empty nodes using eXist-db

Tags: xquery, crud, exist-db

I am trying to remove all empty `<paragraph>` nodes in my XML. Here's what I have:

```
<root>
    <text>
        <paragraph>This is some text</paragraph>
        <paragraph></paragraph>
        <paragraph>More text</paragraph>
    </text>
    <text>
        <paragraph>Another paragraph</paragraph>
        <paragraph></paragraph>
    </text>
</root>
```

And here is my XQuery:

```
let $root-ele as element() := doc("text.xml")/*
return 
    update delete $root-ele/text[paragraph = '']
```

It doesn't seem to be updating the file, but I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code, as written, should delete both `<text>` elements - not the empty `<paragraph>` elements. Let's set that issue aside for now and figure out why your code isn't having *any* effect on the source file.

First, are you sure it isn't having any effect? Depending on your editing environment, you likely need to close and reopen the `text.xml` document before seeing changes.

Once you're sure the document is really not being modified, I would guess that your `doc()` function is not properly selecting the document correctly. To troubleshoot, try supplying the full, absolute path to your document, e.g., `doc('/db/text.xml')` or `doc('/db/apps/my-app/text.xml')`.

Once you confirm that you're correctly addressing the file, use an XPath to confirm that you are selecting the desired nodes, e.g., `doc('/db/test.xml')/root/text/paragraph[. = '']` to select empty paragraphs.

Once you are able to see the desired nodes, I would suggest using a FLWOR to delete each instance in question:

```
for $p in doc('/db/test.xml')/root/text/paragraph[. = '']
return
    update delete $p
```

As the documentation about eXist's XQuery Update syntax makes clear - see paragraph 3 of http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/update_ext.xml#syntax - you should always try to make your update as close to the target node of the update as possible.

> ... be cautious when deleting or replacing nodes that are still being used by enclosing code. This is because a delete or replace will be processed immediately, and the deleted or replaced node will no longer be available to the query... However, an expression like the following [see sample code in link] is safe as it only modifies the current iteration variable...

Comment: Thanks for your help, it turned out the the file path was fine, but most of the problem was that I was using eXide and my browser was caching the response...  and the other issue was that I was selecting the wrong node to delete as you suggested. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good to hear you identified the key blocker - the browser cache. I haven't ever experienced that with eXide, so if you are able to reproduce the conditions that led eXide's responses to be cached, please share them with the exist-open mailing list: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/exist-open. In any case, I'd welcome you to subscribe if you haven't already. It's a great place to ask questions and see what other people are using eXist for.